# Sum of amount for each date having 'type' column in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have table `expense_incomes`, the structure for table is:

```
| id | type    |  amount  |    date      |
|----------------------------------------|
|  1 | Expense |  100     |  2021-04-02  |
|  2 | Expense |  150     |  2021-04-02  |
|  3 | Expense |  150     |  2021-04-03  |
|  4 | Income  |  500     |  2021-04-04  |
|  5 | Expense |  250     |  2021-04-04  |
|----------------------------------------|
```

I want the sum of expenses and incomes in two different arrays groupBy date. 
I have tried this code. (In the above Example) I want to push expense into expense_array and income into income_array for 2021-04-02.

```
$record_by_date = DB::select("SELECT SUM(amount) as 'amount', cast(date as date) dateAdded, type as 'type' FROM expense_incomes GROUP BY cast(date as date), type");
$expenses_array = array();
$incomes_array = array();
$date_array = array();
foreach($record_by_date as $record)
{
  if($record->type == 'Expense') {
      array_push($expenses_array, $record->amount);
      array_push($incomes_array, 0);
  } elseif($record->type == 'Income') {
      array_push($incomes_array, $record->amount);
      array_push($expenses_array, 0);
  }
  array_push($date_array, $record->dateAdded);
}
```

What I am getting now:

```
$expenses_array = [250, 150, 0, 250];
$incomes_array = [0, 0, 500, 0];
$date_array = [2021-04-02, 2021-04-03, 2021-04-04, 2021-04-04];
```

Expected Array Structure:

```
$expenses_array = [250, 150, 250];
$incomes_array = [0, 0, 500];
$date_array = [2021-04-02, 2021-04-03, 2021-04-04];
```

Comment: What is your expected final array structure ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid expected results now added to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want an aggregated query with conditional sum of amount for each date.

In pure SQL it can done using `CASE` statements as

```
select  date as dateAdded,
        sum(case when type='Income' then amount else 0 end) as income,
        sum(case when type='Expense' then amount else 0 end) as expense
from expense_incomes 
group by date 
order by date
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27fcae/1)

In query builder it can be transformed as

```
$data= DB::table("expense_incomes")
            ->select([ "date as dateAdded",
                        DB::raw("sum(case when type='Income' then amount else 0 end) as income"),
                        DB::raw("sum(case when type='Expense' then amount else 0 end) as expense")
            ])
            ->groupBy("date")
            ->orderBy("date")
            ->get();
```

Now you can use collection helper [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) to extract data  for your columns

```
$expenses_array = $data->pluck('expense');
$incomes_array = $data->pluck('income');
$date_array = $data->pluck('dateAdded');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$expensesArray =  DB::select("SELECT SUM(amount) as 'amount', cast(date as date) dateAdded, type as 'type' FROM expense_incomes GROUP BY cast(date as date), type where type = 'Expense'")->toArray();

$incomeArray =  DB::select("SELECT SUM(amount) as 'amount', cast(date as date) dateAdded, type as 'type' FROM expense_incomes GROUP BY cast(date as date), type where type = 'Income'")->toArray();
```

Comment: See the edits please, I have added expected results

Comment: please share your arrays response what you are getting right now.

Comment: I want to get results from single query, because I want there sometimes expense and income on same date

Comment: first of all you print your query result using `dd($record_by_date)`

Comment: I have added current results to the question

Comment: your output is correct but here your logic may be different think expense and income both are added on same date so you get same date twice

Comment: That is why your current output showing four dates and also your loop iterates four times.